# React : Create child components dynamically and avoid re-rendering child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, dynamic

I am new to React. So this may be a very basic question. But am unsure how to solve it.

**The scenario :**
I have 1 parent TileLayout.jsx control. This control will render child Tile controls.
The props passed to this TileLayout.jsx is an object called tilesMetaData.  This tilesMetaData is simply an object which is a list of tiles along with their titles and the webservice url from which to get the tile data :

```
tilesMetaData : {
   key : "some unique key",
   tileMetaData : { title : "string" , webserviceURL : "string"},
   tileData : { some data }
}
```

In the componentWillMount() method, i am retreiving the data for the individual tiles by looping over the tilesMetaData object and getting the webservice url. Once the data is retreived, I am again filling the tilesMetaData object with tileData.

So initially empty tiles with only title is rendered. Once the data comes back the tiles are loaded with the data.

In the render method of the TileLayout.jsx

```
render() {
    const { tilesMetaData } = this.props

    return (
      <div className="tileContainer">
        {
          tilesMetaData.size !== 0
          ?
            Object.keys(tilesMetaData).map((key, index) => (
              <Tile
                tileId={key}
                tileMetaData={tilesMetaData[key].tileMetaData} 
                tileData={tilesMetaData[key].tileData ? tilesMetaData[key].tileData : null}

              />
            ))
          :
            null
          }
      </div>
    )
  }
```

**The problem**
Everytime the tilesMetaData is loaded with the actual tileData, the whole TileLayout control is rerendered. I do not want it to be re-rendered. I only want the respective Tile control whose data is retreived to be re-rendered.

I have tried a couple of things but nothing seems to work. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
YN

Comment: Show us what you have tried?

Comment: Hi, i tried to create the Tile controls via React.createElement method. This way i have a reference of all the tile controls created. And then i can re-render the desired Tile control when the tileData is available. But I couldnt do it that way as the third parameter in the createElement must be child control. And that i cant create here itself.

Comment: I also tried the componentWillUpdate methodology to prevent updates. Somehow that doesnt seem to get called.

Comment: Any help or hint is much appreciated.